# How can I hide the mp4 file from the page source code?

Tags: php

I have a video.php page like this:

```
<?php $videolink = $_GET['urlpath']; ?>
<video width="100%" height="100%" controls autoplay> 
<source src="/videos/<?php echo $videolink; ?>.mp4">
</video>
```

Url Example:

```
http://example.com/video.php?urlpath=video1
```

Sample Url Output:

```
<video width="100%" height="100%" controls autoplay> 
<source src="/videos/video1.mp4">
</video>
```

What I want to do is this: How can I remove '/videos/video1.mp4' from the page source code? Or can I pull it from a different file? I don't want it to appear directly in the page source code, thank you.

Comment: That is not possible unless you use some kind of streaming

Comment: I think it can be done.

If I fetch the .mp4 file with javascript and shoot javascript content remotely; I think it would be if I used javascript with php.

`<script src="/javascript.php?<?php echo $_GET['urlpath'];?>"></script>`

Comment: Yes, it just came to my mind. When I reach the appropriate solution, I share my method.

My goal is not to hide the .mp4 file entirely, but I'm sure they'll find it somehow.

I just don't want it to appear in the page source code.

Dynamically bringing .mp4 remotely with javascript seems to solve my job.

Comment: Use AJAX. After page loads feed in the path. Could also look at HLS. You also are open to XSS.

Comment: @user3783243 Actually I don't think it will be an xss. Data from the Get part only

<source src = "/ videos / THIS SECTION.mp4">

will change the video name. So they will get a 404 Not Found error. I don't think it will create a deficit.

I also don't understand ajax and javascript. How can I use it with Ajax, is there a sample code?

Comment: @xquaL It is. Try something like `example.com/?urlpath=%22%3E%3C%2Fvideo%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert%28%27injected%27%29%3B%3C%2Fscript%3E` It depends how you load your player. See https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/. So you can use document ready to make an ajax request then write the video element with the URL you get back from the AJAX request to your PHP script.

Comment: @user3783243 This didn't work for me. But I can have an alert in a different way yes ..

But any database connection etc. can they do anything other than give an alert because they are not?

How can I prevent this?

I guess I should make sure that only letters and numbers are used in Url.

I think I need to block special characters like (<> '"!% & + ^) from the URL.

I think I can do it with PHP as follows;
`<?php
if (strstr($_GET['urlpath'], '<')) {
//
} else {
echo $videolink;
}?>`

But as if this is not very healthy, what would you suggest?

Comment: A user could alter the whole page to display what they want. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996122/how-to-prevent-xss-with-html-php.